# Stripe.js: No sources on Customer object

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm creating a new customer in stripe using a token created in the user's browser.  This is on parse.com's servers, for what it's worth.  I would like to retain a few details on the card, such as last4, but the customer object shows no sources under sources.data.  Any pointers on how to get this information?  Thanks for your help.

```
return Stripe.Customers.create({
  source: token,
  email: email
}).then(function(rr) {
  console.log(rr.sources);

  [ process response...]
});
```

This is the output:

```
{"object":"list","total_count":1,"has_more":false,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_[removed]/sources","data":[{}]}
```

Comment: can you log rr.sources.data[0]? console.log may just not print all the sub resources

Answer (score 0):

It's bit strange that you are creating a customer but getting the object of customers list (https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#list_customers).

If customer is created successfully at stripe than it should return the customer object. You can check in more details here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer

I suggest here that please check the customer creation code once again at your side.

Comment: He's not getting a list of customers, he's getting a list of sources (the url shows that), where total_count is even equal to one.